# SQLite in Delphi displays single unicode character field incorrectly

Tags: sqlite, delphi, unicode

I am using SQLite to do query locally inside client application. But for string field with only one unicode character, SQLite query can't display it properly. Instead, one unicode character will be displayed as '?' in the grid.

[image: Two queries results in DBGrid]

Here is the code of two types of query, qryV001X runs from SQLite and qryV001Y runs from Firebird DBServer. FireDAC components are using: sqlLocalConn and sqlFirebird are TFDConnection, qryV001X and qryV001Y are TFDQuery.

```
  var
    sqlDriverLink: TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink;
    sqlLocalConn: TFDConnection;
    sqlLocal: TFDLocalSQL;
    sqlFirebird: TFDConnection;
    qryV001X: TFDQuery;
    qryV001Y: TFDQuery;
  begin
    with qryV001X do begin
      Connection := sqlLocalConn;
      SQL.Text := 'SELECT F004, F006 FROM T001;';   
      // T001 is fetched from DBServer by TFDTable inside application.
      // Its records are displayed correctly for all unicode characters.
      Active := True;
    end;

    with qryV001Y do begin
      Connection := sqlFirebird;
      SQL.Text := 'SELECT F004, F006 FROM T001;';
      Active := True;
    end;
  end;
```

[image: sqlFirebird]  [image: sqlLocalConn]

[New update] Here is the calling structure for two queries.

[image: calling structure]

The only difference between sqlLocalConn and sqlFirebird is that one uses SQLite as DriverName and anyone uses FB.

Is there any setting in SQLite for unicode support or I did something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What field type is the field which doesn't display correctly?

Comment: Field type is ftString. It is defined in Firebird, I don't know if SQLite needs to configure its field type and how to do this. In my program, I didn't assign field type by code. They should be picked up from database through TFDConnection directly.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused:  you say "is defined in Firebird,", but FireBird has nothing to do with Sqlite.  In any case, if the column is a Unicode type **in the Sqlite** database, the field type in your Delphi app should be ftWideString, not ftString.  If you haven't already, define persistent TFields on your FDQuery that accesses the Sqlite db.  Btw, your q would be far clearer if you just remove all refernces to Firebird.

Comment: Btw, to define persistent TFields, right-click the Sqlite FDQuery  and select"Fields Editor ..." from the menu.

Comment: @MartynA do you have a blog?

Comment: @MichaelRiley-AKAGunny:  I'm afraid not.  Should I have?  I have toyed with the idea, if only as a place for odd bits of code people here might find useful ...

Comment: @MartynA I'd find it very useful. Your knowledge about Delphi is worth sharing. :-)

Comment: @MartynA I also find many of your comments/answers to be useful :-)

Comment: @MichaelRiley-AKAGunny and Dave, that's very kind of you to say, so maybe I'll have a go.  Ironically, since I retired a few years back, most of what I've learned about Delphi has come from attempting to answer SO questions.

Comment: @MartynA Sorry for my unclear description. Now I made a simple diagram to show the relationship among all components. Hope it is better than my message.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't make any difference to my comment, really.  Have you checked the FieldType of the field in your qryV001x or not, and is it type ftString or ftWideString?  I think you will find that it has to be ftWideString for its value to be correctly displayed.

Comment: @MartynA Thank you very much for your quick answer. I didn't use persistent field in qryV001X, so its fieldtype should be assigned automatically. That might be the reason for this kind of issue. Is there a solution to force its fieldtype to be ftWideString inside qryV001X query? I would like it can be assigned or changed during runtime, not designtime. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just create persistent fields for now, to see whether it works.  It is easy to create fields at runtime, but don't worry about that for now.

Comment: I just checked fieldtype for both query. qryV001X (with ? mark) has ftWideString fieldtype, and another one, qryV001Y (display unicode correctly) has ftString fieldtype. It is strange to me. Here is the testing code:     if FieldByName('F006').DataType = ftString then
      ShowMessage('qryV001X: ftString')
    else if FieldByName('F006').DataType = ftWideString then
      ShowMessage('qryV001X: ftWideString');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213155/discussion-between-james-and-martyna).

Comment: Sorry, I don't do chats.  I think you should replace (most of) the contents of your q by the [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that you should be providing if you expect help here.  I am not spending any more time on it until you do.